# pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError in python

Tags: python, pytube

I can try to find youtube videos in different formats. using pytube streams filter but it gives an error pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError.

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = input('Enter url :')

link = YouTube(url)

print(link.title)

obj = link.streams.filter(progressive="True")
print(obj)
```

This error given :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 170, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 293, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 279, in get_throttling_function_name
    caller="get_throttling_function_name", pattern="multiple"
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 44, in <module>
    yt = myVideo.streams.filter(type='mp4')
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 285, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 177, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 293, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "/home/jay/PycharmProjects/videoinfo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 279, in get_throttling_function_name
    caller="get_throttling_function_name", pattern="multiple"
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

I can also reinstall pytube using "**pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git**" and also "**pip install pytube**". but the error is still now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was making a youtube video downloader but pytube is giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956373/i-was-making-a-youtube-video-downloader-but-pytube-is-giving-error)

Comment: What is the _full_ error message? What are you entering as the `url`?

Comment: I have an entering YouTube video URL as input. @Chris

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can install :

```
pip install pytube==11.0.1 or pip install --upgrade pytube
```

or you can change in pytube/cipher.py :

```
edit line:r'a\.[A-Z]&&\(b=a\.[sg]et\("n"\)\)&&\(b=([^(]+)\(b\),a\.[sg]et\("n",b\)\)}};'
```

to

```
r'a\.C&&\(b=a\.get\("n"\)\)&&\(b=([^(]+)\(b\),a\.set\("n",b\)\)}};',
```

in the **def get_throttling_function_name(js: str) -> str:** function.