# I was making a youtube video downloader but pytube is giving error

Tags: python, pytube

```py
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVcjVsk29XQ')

streams = yt.streams.filter(adaptive=True)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 170, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 293, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 278, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\YtDownload\yt.py", line 5, in <module>
    streams = yt.streams.filter(adaptive=True)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 285, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 177, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 293, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "C:\Users\Sanskar\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 278, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue have been solved in the latest version
so upgrade to the latest version like this

```py
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

or on windows

```py
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```